# bash autocomplete not working after "cvs commit"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cvs

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. When I'm on the server via Putty (ssh), the autocomplete is not working for the "cvs commit" or "cvs update", although for other commands like nano, it's working fine.

eg, when I'm in a directory and try

```
nano cvsd<<tab>>
```

this is completed to cvsdir/ (to be filled then with the actual filename of course)

however, when I'm in the same location and try

```
cvs commit cvsd<<tab>>
```

nothing happens. It's not completed. I tried in different locations (for folders that are cvs folders), and it's never working. When I type  cvs commit cvsdir, it's working as expected - the directory actually is a cvs directory.

How come ? How can I change it? How an I ensure that the auto-complete works again for the cvs command?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/95211/how-do-i-set-up-bash-completion-for-command-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking into the comment of Pumbaa80

Reposted the question on askubuntu since I couldn't find the answer. Hope somebody can help me out...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/476189/cvs-autocomplete-not-working

Answer (score 0):

The "bash-completion" package contains a lot of custom completion scripts for various commands. Some of them match the commands very well, some of them are ... of lesser quality.

The most common problem is that they make unwarranted assumptions that certain things you would normally be able to auto-complete (probably directories in this care) are invalid for this command. In reality the author of the script is putting in a limitation that is their preference rather than a correct limit.

This should probably be raised as a Ubuntu bug, or at least a mis-feature.